# Why is cos and sin used in plotting this phase portrait

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matlab

I'm plotting the phase portrait of the following system of ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x + 3 y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = -5 x + 2 y$

The code I have in matlab:

```
function d=dxdt1(t,x)
d=[ x(1)+3*x(2); -5*x(1)+2*x(2) ];
```

Then the following plots a number of trajectories

```
figure(1)
hold on 
for theta=[0:10]*pi/5
    x0=1e-5*[cos(theta);sin(theta)];
    [t,x]=ode45(@dxdt1,[0 8],x0);
    plot(x(:,1),x(:,2))
end
```

As you can see, the code that plots each trajectory references the function dxdt1  defined earlier.

QUESTION

I don't understand the use of pi, cos and sin in this code. Namely it seems that the domain is cos and sin of 1...10 * pi.

I don't see why it's necessary to use cos and sin in the domain instead of just a simple continuous interval such as from -50 to 50.

Any help on this one?

The output of the code:

[image: Output of the code above]

Comment: Maybe those initial conditions make the phase portrait look nicer and more like a spiral. Make $x_0$ something like [1, -1] and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary at all. All it does is decide the initial condition for each of the curves in the plot. So, what `sin, cos, pi` allow the code authors to do is to make ten starting points evenly spaced around a small circle centred on the origin.

Note the `/5` there. That makes the `theta` go, not from $0$ to $10\pi$, but from $0$ to $2\pi$. Then taking sine and cosine of `theta` makes a circle, and `1e-5` makes the circle small (radius $10^{-5}$).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very insightful. i think in my post I was confusing the initial conditions with something else.